# linux - disable use of keyboard button system wide

Tags: linux, keyboard

Can I disable a set of keys on my entire system?   I often hit the back tick key whenever I hit the tab button and was wondering if there was a way to stop it from firing.  Or is the only solution to just physically tare it off the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by remapping the back-tick key.
For more information: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys